# Gerar valores repetidos no R

Tags: r

No data frame abaixo quero que os nos dias que nao tem informacao de ganho que o ganho seja repetido com base sempre na ultima informacao coletada. Por exemplo do dia 2 ao dia 15 o ganho será de 0.97 e do dia 79 a 86 de 0.45 Como posso fazer isso no R?

<

```css
Dia Ganho
2 0.97
16 0.95
23 1.03
24 0.99
30 1.03
37 1.01
44 1.11
51 1.04
58 1.31
65 1.17
72 1.09
79 0.45
86
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O pacote `zoo` contem a função `na.locf` que faz exatamente o que você precisa. Segundo a descrição da mesma, é uma função genérica que substitui cada `NA` com o mais recente `non-NA` anterior. Segue código utilizando essa função

```
df <- data.frame(
  Dia = c(2,16,23,24,30,37,44,51,58,65,72,79,86),
  Ganho = c(.97,.95,1.03,.99,1.03,1.01,1.11,1.04,1.31,1.17,1.09,.45,NA)
)
temp <- expand.grid(Dia = seq(from = min(df$Dia), to = max(df$Dia), by = 1))
df <- merge(df, temp, all = T)
library(zoo)
df <- na.locf(df)
```

Comment: Esta funcao é adequada para o que eu preciso. Nesse exemplo que eu passei tem informacao de ganho de um só animal. Tu saberia me dizer como posso aplicar essa funcao que voce passou para um dataset com vários animais (100 animais). Pensei em usar um loop (for animal in 1 1:100), mas nao sei como aplicar nessa sua funcao

Comment: Essa função funciona para um `data.frame` com mais de uma coluna. Vou até editar minha resposta dado que nela, eu aplico especificamente na variável `Ganho`

Answer (score 5):

Tente o código abaixo. Creio que é o que quer.

```
resultado <- lapply(seq_along(dados$Dia)[-nrow(dados)], function(i) {
    data.frame(Dia = seq(dados$Dia[i], dados$Dia[i + 1] - 1), Ganho = dados$Ganho[i])
})
resultado <- do.call(rbind, resultado)
resultado <- rbind(resultado, data.frame(Dia = dados$Dia[nrow(dados)],
                                         Ganho = resultado$Ganho[nrow(resultado)]))
resultado
```

**DADOS.**

```
dados <-
structure(list(Dia = c(2L, 16L, 23L, 24L, 30L, 37L, 44L, 51L, 
58L, 65L, 72L, 79L, 86L), Ganho = c(0.97, 0.95, 1.03, 0.99, 1.03, 
1.01, 1.11, 1.04, 1.31, 1.17, 1.09, 0.45, NA)), .Names = c("Dia", 
"Ganho"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -13L))
```

Comment: Rodei teu código aqui e me pareceu que há linhas com dias repetidos no `resultado`, mas ganhos diferentes.

Comment: @MarcusNunes Tem razão. Erro corrigido.